# Linear algebra text that covers Hamming codes

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm teaching linear algebra next year and need to choose a text. It's an introductory course, with mostly sophomores. Many years ago, I taught such a course from a text that I remember liking a lot, but I cannot remember what it was. One thing I remember clearly was that it had a delightful chapter on binary linear codes, like Hamming codes. In searching, I see lots of books about coding theory, but I'm not finding many that are aimed at a first course in linear algebra with an excursion into codes, like the book I remember. I'm wondering if someone here would recognize this description and point me toward the book (or another one, if you like it).

(I thought the book I used was by Rotman, but now when I search I don't find that he ever wrote a linear algebra text.)

Comment: Maybe you used Linear Algebra: a modern introduction of David Poole? I think he mentioned the application of linear algebra in coding theory, but the 3th version doesn't have a whole chapter on that topic. 4th version has an online chapter on coding theory, but I don't know how to access that chapter though.

Comment: Isn't it one of the numerous books by Gilbert Strang ? I have especialy appreciated his remarkable "Linear algebra and learning from data" (published around 10 years). I don't remember if coding theory is especialy developed there.